# cpanel gives error laravel : Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, cpanel

I am trying to install laravel through `composer install`

it shows me error :

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
```

```
  Problem 1
    - league/flysystem is locked to version 1.1.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - league/flysystem 1.1.4 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
  Problem 2
    - league/mime-type-detection is locked to version 1.7.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - league/mime-type-detection 1.7.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
  Problem 3
    - league/flysystem 1.1.4 requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - laravel/framework v8.50.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.4].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v8.50.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.\
```

and also composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: I think we get it! ___trying to install laravel through composer install___ But when you get told when writing a question that there is not enough explanation in the question compared to the code, **DONT JUST DUPLICATE A PIECE**

Answer (score -1):

just remove composer lock file and vendor folder. then run composer install

Comment: it shows error ` No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file. `